# Query questions based on two tags

Tags: support

is it somehow possible to query wordpress.stackexchange for multiple tags? I would like to e.g. see all QAs tagged with comment + plugin?

Answer (score 5):

Set the tags in brackets: `[comments] [plugins]`:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments+plugins

You can also exclude tags: `[youtube] -[videos]`

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube+-videos